# If and else condition is not working inside forEach loop in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have multiple div elements it will load dynamically through ng-repeat.

- I have six dynamic rows with **"view all"** button.
- If I click that button i will pass the **id** in a parameter. So that the particular id is clicking. But my need is,
- If I click the particular **"view all"** button, I need to hide only that particular button and I want to show the **"close"** button instead of that **"view All"** and I need to change the style for two divs **( class name is "container-body and object-thumb")**.
- But for me, in my if condition it is coming correctly. But for example if I am going to click 4 th row, it will come indise that if condition. But loop is still not ending. So it is going 5th and 6th row also in else condition. So it is not working for me.
- How can I do this. Can anyone tell me.

```js
$scope.viewData = function (stuid) {
$scope.getAll.forEach(function (pillar) {
        $scope.names.forEach(function (name) {
          if(name.id == pillarid){
            angular.element('.addViewCards').addClass('fullViewCards');
            angular.element('.addcardsMargin').addClass('removeMargin');
          }else{
            angular.element('.addViewCards').removeClass('fullViewCards');
            angular.element('.addcardsMargin').removeClass('removeMargin');
          }
          
});
});
}
```

```css
.fullViewCards{
    display: inline-block !important;
}
.removeMargin{
    margin: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-body" ng-class="value.length > 5 ? 'addViewCards' : ''">
                        <div class="object-thumb" ng-repeat="card in value | orderBy:'cardorder'" ng-class="{'addcardsMargin' : value.length > 5}">
                        
</div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="viewData(value[0].stuid)">View All</button></li>
```

Comment: remove the if, instead do `let isToggled = name.id == pillarid;` `angular.element('.addViewCards').toggleClass('fullViewCards', isToggled);` and `angular.element('.addcardsMargin').toggleClass('removeMargin', isToggled);`

Comment: still i'm getting the same error. If i click 2nd button, first isToggle is true, the it is loopng again and finaly it is going to false.

Comment: By definition a `forEach` call only ends after it has iterated over the entire array, as in, *for each* element in this array call this function on it. If you need to selectively loop then you need a conventional for loop that you can break out of early.

Comment: @DrewReese can you tell me how? If I take last value, it won't work right?

Comment: @sathishkumar could you create a simple fiddle?

Comment: @sathishkumar Use a standard for-loop, i.e. `for (let i = 0; i < $scope.names.length; i++) {...` and when you get to the indexed element that matches what you want to toggle, toggle the classes and `break;` out of the loop, you're done. It may actually be easier to just use one of the array searching functions to return the element you actually want to toggle. Something like `let element = $scope.names.find(name => name .id === pillarId);` which will do the same thing as looping yourself. Just remember `array::find` returns `undefined` if nothing found/matches.